# How do you destroy an object in its constructor and return NULL

Tags: c++, pointers

I am trying to write a cpp module that must check for proper initialization. It needs to be initialized with at least one non-NULL pointer. If not, it needs to delete itself and return NULL. The following program does seem to destroy the object, but it doesn't seem to return null.

What's going on here?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class cmod {
public:
        cmod(int *p1=NULL, int *p2=NULL)
        {
                if( p1 == NULL && p2 == NULL){
                        delete(this);
                }
                else
                        cout << __func__ << ": Initialized" << endl;
                if(p1 != NULL)
                        cout << "*p1 = " << *p1 << endl;
                if(p2 !=NULL)
                        cout << "*p2 = " << *p2 << endl;
        }
        ~cmod()
        {
                cout << __func__ << ": Destroyed" << endl;
        }

};

int main()
{
        int a=10, b = 20;
        cmod *p = new cmod();
        if(p == NULL)
                cout << __func__ << ": Unable to initialize" << endl;
        cmod *p1 = new cmod(&a, &b);
}
```

The following is the output:

```
~cmod: Destroyed
cmod: Initialized
*p1 = 10
*p2 = 2
```

Why is the line `Unable to initialize` not printing?

UPDATE:
After looking at all the answers, I came up with the following:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class cmod {
private:
        int *l1,*l2;
        cmod()
        {
                throw std::runtime_error("Failed to construct object.   No arguements");
        }
        cmod(int *p1=NULL, int *p2=NULL)
        {
                if( p1 == NULL && p2 == NULL){
                        throw std::runtime_error("Failed to construct object. Both args NULL");
                }
                else
                        cout << __func__ << ": Initialized" << endl;
                if(p1 != NULL)
                        l1 = p1;
                if(p2 !=NULL)
                        l2 = p2;
        }
        ~cmod()
        {
                cout << __func__ << ": Destroyed" << endl;
        }
public:
        static cmod * initialize(int *p1=NULL, int *p2 = NULL)
        {
                if( p1 == NULL && p2 == NULL){
                        return NULL;
                }
                else
                        return new cmod(p1,p2);

        }
        void dump()
        {
                cout << __func__ << ": a = " << *l1 << endl;
                cout << __func__ << ": b = " << *l2 << endl;

        }
int main()
{
        int a=10, b = 20;
        cmod *p = cmod::initialize(NULL, NULL);
        if(p == NULL)
                cout << __func__ << ": Unable to initialize" << endl;
        cmod *p1 = cmod::initialize(&a, &b);
        if(p!=NULL)
                p->dump();
        if(p1!=NULL)
                p1->dump();
}
```

Is this a proper approach now?

Comment: `delete` does not set the pointer to `nullptr`.

Comment: I can't think of another way to put this: Don't do that.

Comment: You'll probably need to override the `new` operator for `class cmod` (though there is probably a better way to implement the whole thing, i.e., a design pattern specifically for this purpose).

Comment: If you want to signal object construction failure, use exceptions.

Comment: Since calling the constructor with two NULL pointers is not allowed, the default argument for the first pointer should never be used, so get rid of it.

Comment: what is the point in calling destructor in constructor? please ask a correct question

Comment: The idea is to ensure that you do not have a faulty initialization because this will be the stub for a hardware library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to validate the input before constructing an object, it will be better to use a `static` member function that does that instead of validating the input in the constructor. Also, make the constructor `private` to prevent accidental misuse.

```
class cmod {

   public:

      static cmod* buildInstance(int *p1=NULL, int *p2=NULL)
      {
         if( p1 == NULL && p2 == NULL){
            return NULL;
         }
         else {
            return new cmd(p1, p2);
         }
      }

      ~cmod()
      {
         cout << __func__ << ": Destroyed" << endl;
      }

   private:

      cmod(int *p1, int *p2)
      {
         cout << __func__ << ": Initialized" << endl;
         if(p1 != NULL)
            cout << "*p1 = " << *p1 << endl;
         if(p2 !=NULL)
            cout << "*p2 = " << *p2 << endl;
      }

};
```

and then use it as:

```
int main()
{
   int a=10, b = 20;
   cmod *p = mod::buildInstance();
   if(p == NULL)
      cout << __func__ << ": Unable to initialize" << endl;
   cmod *p1 = cmod::buildInstance(&a, &b);
}
```

Comment: How will you protect it against calling without any arguments as walter pointed out?

Comment: @preetam, the constructor is `private`. `buildInstance()` validates the input before calling the constructor.

Answer (score 10):

The constructor will always return an object of it's class, unless it throws an exception. So what you want to do is instead this:

```
cmod(int *p1=NULL, int *p2=NULL)
{
    if( p1 == NULL && p2 == NULL)
        throw std::runtime_error("Failed to construct object.");
}
```

Comment: And of course, to `catch` it at `cmod *p = new cmod();`.

Comment: @barakmanos, of course (unless you want this to be a fatal error, but then you'd call std::terminate() instead.)

Comment: this wont be a fatal error as I will be initializing a lot of these objects. Is there also a way to ensure that only this form of initialization happens? Sorry for the silly questions. c guy moving into cpp. bear with me.

Comment: @preetam: make the constructor(s) private and provide a static "factory" function (`make_foo(...)`) that does the checking before attempting to create your object.

Answer (score 3):

You must not `delete this`. Consider what happens in the following scenario:

```
cmod A;  // default constructor: called with both arguments NULL
```

when `A` is not allocated on the heap, but lives on the stack. But calling `delete` with a pointer that was not allocated by `new` is a faulty program (if you're lucky it will crash at run time).

As Harald pointed out, the **appropriate and correct way to deal with bad input to a constructor is to throw and exception**. Using a factory is not fully appropriate, as users may still attempt to construct an object by other means (unless that is prohibited by making the factory a `friend` and the constructor `private` or `protected`).

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a factory pattern for creation of objects so that object creation is delegated to factory. This way factory can control whether the object should be created or not.

So create another class called cmodFactory which has a static method which returns cmod. In this static method, you can check if you want to create the object or not and return accordingly.

Adding the example code:

```
 #include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class cmod {
public:
        cmod(int *p1=NULL, int *p2=NULL)
        {
                cout << __func__ << ": Initialized" << endl;
                if(p1 != NULL)
                        cout << "*p1 = " << *p1 << endl;
                if(p2 !=NULL)
                        cout << "*p2 = " << *p2 << endl;
        }
        ~cmod()
        {
                cout << __func__ << ": Destroyed" << endl;
        }

};

class cmodFactory {
public:
        static cmod * getCmodInstance(int *p1=NULL, int *p2=NULL)
        {
                if( p1 == NULL && p2 == NULL){
                       return NULL;
                }
                else
                {
                  cmod * instance = new cmod(p1, p2);
                  return instance;
                }
        }

};

int main()
{
        int a=10, b = 20;
        cmod *p = cmodFactory::getCmodInstance();
        if(p == NULL)
                cout << __func__ << ": Unable to initialize" << endl;
       p = cmodFactory::getCmodInstance(&a, &b);

        if(p == NULL)
                cout << __func__ << ": Unable to initialize" << endl;
        else 
          cout << __func__ << ": initialized" << endl;


}
```

Output is

```
main: Unable to initialize
cmod: Initialized
*p1 = 10
*p2 = 20
main: initialized
```

Comment: This is a good answer. Perhaps a coding example will make it even better.

Comment: This code still calls `delete(this)` and allows construction other than by the factory.

Comment: Need to find a way to protect the first class's constructor though

Answer (score 1):

A constructor cannot return null. A constructor does not return a pointer. Calling `delete(this)` within a constructor is all kinds of wrong.

There is a way to cancel construction of an object: Throw an exception. In that situation the new-expression doesn't return null, though. In fact, it does not return at all. Instead you must catch the exception to handle that case.

> Why is the "Unable to initialize not printing ?

Because new expression never returns null unless the non-throwing variant is used and allocation (which is separate from the initialization of the object) fails. In this case allocation didn't fail and a throwing variant (the default) was used.